# 「てほしい」の使い方を教えてください

Tags: grammar

> 厚生労働省は、たばこをやめたい人は病院に相談してほしいと言っています。

厚生労働省はタバコをやめたい人に病院に相談にしてほしいということでしょうね。でも、どうして「やめたい人に」の代わりに「やめたい人は」を使っているか分かりません。

Answer (score 3):

厚労省は「A」と言っている、という形においてAの部分を ある程度 独立した文として言い表したいからだと思います。その中で何を主題にすべきかを考えれば、「自分たち」ではなく「タバコをやめたい人」になるでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have several は in the same sentence.
According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar". page 518:
"When more than one は appears in a sentence, the first は is usually understood to be the topic marker, the second は is more contrastive than the first one, the third is more contrastive than the second, and so on."

Example:
太郎はテニスは出来ます。
Taro can play tennis.(but he can't play other things)

So 厚生労働省は is the topic of the sentence.
But たばこをやめたい人は is contrastive.

People who want to quit smoking should go to a hospital, but people who want to quit gum, for example, don't need to go to a hospital.